# I am attempting to populate a picklist with the names of a custom object but my picklist isn't populating and I'm not sure why

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist

I am going through the Lightning Framework Specialist Superbadge and am stuck with my names not populating into a `lightning-select` component. At this point I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further as I've verified my helper is correctly pulling the names and IDs of all of these objects, it just isn't adding them to the picklist.

BoatSearchForm.cmp `lightning-select`:

```
 <lightning:select aura:id="boatTypes" label="Please select" name="selectType" onchange="{!c.handleChange}">
            <option value="">All Types</option>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.BoatTypes}" var="boatType">
                      <option value="{!boatType.Id}" text="{!boatType.Name}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

BoatSearchFormController.js :

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        helper.loadBoatTypes(component);
        var createNewBoat = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        if (createNewBoat) {
            component.set("v.renderNew", true);
        }else{
            component.set("v.renderNew", false);
        }
    },

    handleChange : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log(component.find("boatTypes").get("v.value"));
        component.set("v.selectedType", component.find("boatTypes").get("v.value"));
    }
```

BoatSearchFormHelper.js

```
 loadBoatTypes: function (component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getBoatTypes");
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.options", response.getReturnValue()) //this returns a value but does not appear to set the component
            }

            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                            errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
```

Comment: Hi Josh, mind sharing with us where exactly in the code you are facing issues? is your callback returning a response? is your attribute being populated correctly? since this is a superbadge challenge, it is preferable you be very specific on the issue you are facing vs asking for help with what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi glls, I just added a comment as you posted, but if I do `console.log(response.getReturnValue())` in my helper then I get a list of IDs and Names as expected, but setting the component appears to be failing as my picklist isn't populating with anything except that default value I gave in the markup

Comment: you will need to valdiate/clarify what type of attribute you have set for BoatTypes, if its not a list, then it is normal that your iteration is not working

Comment: It's an array of BoatType objects `<aura:attribute name="BoatTypes" type="BoatType__c[]" />`

Comment: in that case, i dont know why you are setting v.options with the returned array rather thatn v.BoatTypes as mentioned bellow by david

Comment: Yep, that did it. I started coding this one way and changed halfway through, forgot to update the component I was setting and didn't see this somehow until discussing it here. Thanks!

Comment: glad you were able to resolve =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's set these things next to each other:

```
<lightning:select aura:id="boatTypes" label="Please select" name="selectType" onchange="{!c.handleChange}">
            <option value="">All Types</option>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.BoatTypes}" var="boatType">
                      <option value="{!boatType.Id}" text="{!boatType.Name}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

and

```
component.set("v.options", response.getReturnValue()) //this returns a value but does not set the compoenent;
```

Remember that `component` in your JavaScript is a reference to your component, the parent of the `<lightning:select>`.

The `select` component is populated via an iteration over a list in an attribute `v.BoatTypes`. Is that the correct attribute declared in your component?

The server callback is populating your results in an attribute called `v.options` on your component (*not* on the `select` component). Is that attribute declared in your component? Is it the correct attribute? Is it linked to `v.BoatTypes`?

Comment: Changing `component.set("v.options", response.getReturnValue())` to `component.set("v.BoatTypes", response.getReturnValue())` resolved my issue, thanks!